# How to make a RigidBody "look_at" another spatial

Tags: 3d, camera, rotation, focus, godot

I'm using a RigidBody as a player and I have a camera as a child of the RigidBody. The player should look at another spatial (Player 2) at all times. When using a kinematicBody the function look_at() did the job, however the suggested function look_follow() from the godot docs doesn't follow the object the full 360 degrees.

This is what I have so far:

```
extends RigidBody

func _ready():
    Player2 = get_node("/root/Level/Player2")

func look_follow_x(state, current_transform, target_position):
    var up_dir = Vector3(0, 1, 0)
    var cur_dir = current_transform.basis.xform(Vector3(0, 0, 1))
    var target_dir = (target_position - current_transform.origin).normalized()
    var rotation_angle = acos(cur_dir.x) - acos(-target_dir.x)

    state.set_angular_velocity(up_dir * (rotation_angle / state.get_step()))

func _integrate_forces(state):


    var target = Player2.get_transform().origin
    look_follow_x(state, get_global_transform(), target)
```

Right now, when I move the "player" with apply_impulse it follows the other player for the 180 degrees on one side of the X axis, and for the other 180 degrees it inverts the rotation. I don't see what is doing this and therefor don't know how to fix it.

So how would I make the player look at the second player from every position (360 degrees)?